# Flutter SIGINT error on run all tests on VSCODE

Tags: testing, flutter, visual-studio-code, sigint

When trying to "Run All Tests" from flutter/dart on VSCODE, I'm getting a SIGINT error and the test finish with "loading"on file, only the first one goes ok. The problem is that the same thing does not happen if I run the tests one by one.

```
loading /Users/marciomontenegro/Documents/Projects/mel/test/domain/usecases/sign_in_test.dart:

ERROR: Failed to load "/Users/marciomontenegro/Documents/Projects/mel/test/domain/usecases/sign_in_test.dart":
Shell subprocess terminated by ^C (SIGINT, -2) before connecting to test harness.
Test: /Users/marciomontenegro/Documents/Projects/mel/test/domain/usecases/sign_in_test.dart
Shell: /Users/marciomontenegro/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/flutter_tester


dart:async/stream_controller.dart 595:43                     _StreamController.addError
dart:async/stream_controller.dart 862:13                     _StreamSinkWrapper.addError
package:stream_channel/src/guarantee_channel.dart 144:14     _GuaranteeSink._addError
package:stream_channel/src/guarantee_channel.dart 135:5      _GuaranteeSink.addError
package:flutter_tools/src/test/flutter_platform.dart 566:27  FlutterPlatform._startTest
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async/zone.dart 1053:19                                 _CustomZone.registerUnaryCallback
dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart 71:23                      _asyncThenWrapperHelper
package:flutter_tools/src/test/flutter_platform.dart         FlutterPlatform._startTest
package:flutter_tools/src/test/flutter_platform.dart 368:36  FlutterPlatform.loadChannel
package:flutter_tools/src/test/flutter_platform.dart 321:46  FlutterPlatform.load
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async/zone.dart 1053:19                                 _CustomZone.registerUnaryCallback
dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart 71:23                      _asyncThenWrapperHelper
package:test_core/src/runner/loader.dart                     Loader.loadFile.<fn>
package:test_core/src/runner/load_suite.dart 98:31           new LoadSuite.<fn>.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async/zone.dart 1045:19                                 _CustomZone.registerCallback
dart:async/zone.dart 962:22                                  _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded
dart:async/timer.dart 52:45                                  new Timer
dart:async/timer.dart 89:9                                   Timer.run
dart:async/future.dart 172:11                                new Future
package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart 399:21             Invoker._onRun.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
```

Comment: Still an issue...

Answer (score 2):

Just found some info about this issue.
From https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2082 :

```
Ok, I can only repro this using launch.json and not with the Run All Tests command. The reason for this is that Run All Tests runs without the debugger, but setting up launch.json as as described at #1673 (comment) will run in debug mode, but in a single debug session (and that fails due to multiple VM services).

I don't think there's going to be an easy way to handle this.
```

```
As a workaround, if you add "noDebug": true to the launch.json, it should fix it (albeit at the expense of debugging, and a warning from VS Code that it's not a valid option).
```